# Developer Authentication in Amazon Cognito

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, authentication, amazon-cognito

I tried to follow [**this**](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforandroid/developerguide/cognito-auth.html) and [**this**](http://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx1YVAQ4NZKBWF5/Amazon-Cognito-Announcing-Developer-Authenticated-Identities) tutorial but I am unsure if this is how it should be done. I am using **CognitoSync** and I am facing exception of *"Identity_id and dataset_name not unique"* when I try to start the **Sync Service**.

On Amazon Console I have created an IdentityPool and gave the package name of Server Side class i.e. "com.leversystems.devauth" as DeveloperProvider, and used this in Server Class as well as in Android Application.
In Server Class

> map.put("com.leversystems.devauth", "someUniqueId");

In Android App

> logins.put("com.leversystems.devauth", cognitoProvider.getToken());

*Here is my code*

**Java Server Side**

```
package com.leversystems.devauth;
import java.util.HashMap;

import com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidentity.AmazonCognitoIdentityClient;
import com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidentity.model.GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentityRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidentity.model.GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentityResult;

public class DevAuth {

    private BasicAWSCredentials credentials = null;

    private String myAwsAccessKey = "myaccesskey";
    private String myAwsSecretKey = "mysecretkey";
    private String identityPoolID = "identityPoolid";
    private String authARN = "arn:aws:iam::782936514542:role/DefaultRole";

    private String identityId;
    private String token;

    public DevAuth()
    {
        identityId = "No id has been set yet!";
        token = "No token has been set yet!";
        initializeSecurity();
    }

    public String getToken()
    {
        return this.token;
    }

    public String getIdentityId()
    {
        return this.identityId;     
    }

    public void initializeSecurity(){

        credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(myAwsAccessKey , myAwsSecretKey);
        AmazonCognitoIdentityClient client = 
          new AmazonCognitoIdentityClient(credentials);
        GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentityRequest tokenRequest = 
          new GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentityRequest();
        tokenRequest.setIdentityPoolId(identityPoolID);
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

        map.put("com.leversystems.devauth", "nameid.number@provider.com");

        //Duration of the generated OpenID Connect Token
        tokenRequest.setLogins(map);

        tokenRequest.setTokenDuration(1000l);

        GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentityResult result 
           = client.getOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity(tokenRequest);
        this.identityId = result.getIdentityId();
        this.token = result.getToken();
    }}
```

I have made a webservice of this class and in another class **Bridge Class** i am calling this function, that sends the token and id to Android Application. This is working fine, I am getting Token and IdentityId in Android Application.

**Android Classes**

MainActivity Class

```
package com.leversystems.authserver;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCognitoIdentityProvider;
import com.amazonaws.auth.CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.cognito.CognitoSyncManager;
import com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.cognito.Dataset;
import com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.cognito.Dataset.SyncCallback;
import com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.cognito.Record;
import com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.cognito.SyncConflict;
import com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.cognito.exceptions.DataStorageException;
import com.amazonaws.regions.Regions;
import com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidentity.AmazonCognitoIdentity;
import com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidentity.model.GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentityRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidentity.model.GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentityResult;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.JsonArray;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;
import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient;
import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

AWSCognitoIdentityProvider cognitoProvider;
CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider;
AmazonCognitoIdentity identityClient;
GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentityRequest idRequest;
GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentityResult idResp;
CognitoSyncManager client;

Dataset dataset;
TextView tv1;
TextView tv2;
TextView tv3;

Button btn1;
Button btn2;

final String ACC_ID = "myAccountID";
final String IDENTITY_POOL_ID = "identityPoolId";
final String AUTHORIZATION_ARN = "DefaultRole";
final String ACCESS_KEY = "myAccessKey";
final String SECRET_KEY = "mySecretKey";

Credentials cred;

public class Credentials {
    String identityId;
    String token;
}

            @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    playerName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    currentLevel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    highScore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);

    btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    btn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);

    initCognito();

    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            displayCogntioSyncData();
        }
    });

    btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            addCognitoSyncData();
        }
    });

    btn3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            wipeCognitoSyncData();
        }
    });

}

private void initCognito() {

    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
            .permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    client.get(
            "http://192.168.1.112:8080/AuthenticationService/services/auth/gctbda",
            new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
                // When the response returned by REST has Http response code
                // '200'
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(String response) {
                    try {
                        Gson gson = new Gson();
                        JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
                        JsonArray resultArray = jsonParser.parse(response)
                                .getAsJsonArray();

                        for (JsonElement credProvider : resultArray) {
                            cred = gson.fromJson(credProvider,
                                    Credentials.class);
                            BYOIProvider.identityId = cred.identityId;
                            BYOIProvider.token = cred.token;
                            System.out.println("Id: " + cred.identityId);
                            System.out.println("Token: " + cred.token);
                        }
                        syncCognito();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.err.println("Exception in OnSuccess: "
                                + e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            });
}

private void syncCognito() {

    cognitoProvider = new BYOIProvider(ACC_ID, IDENTITY_POOL_ID);


    credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
            getApplicationContext(), cognitoProvider, null,
            AUTHORIZATION_ARN);

    cognitoProvider.refresh();

    HashMap<String, String> logins = new HashMap<String, String>();

    logins.put("com.leversystems.devauth", cognitoProvider.getToken());

    credentialsProvider.setLogins(logins);

    credentialsProvider.refresh();

    client = new CognitoSyncManager(getApplicationContext(),
            IDENTITY_POOL_ID, Regions.US_EAST_1, credentialsProvider);

    dataset = client.openOrCreateDataset("GameInfo");

    synchronize();
}

private void wipeCognitoSyncData() {
    client.wipeData();
    dataset.delete();
    synchronize();
}

private void addCognitoSyncData() {

    dataset.put("playerName", "Muneeb");
    dataset.put("currentLevel", "29");
    dataset.put("highScore", "120345");

    synchronize();

}

private void displayCogntioSyncData() {
    synchronize();

    playerName.setText(dataset.get("playerName"));
    currentLevel.setText(dataset.get("currentLevel"));
    highScore.setText(dataset.get("highScore"));

}

private void synchronize() {

    dataset.synchronize(new SyncCallback() {

        @Override
        public boolean onConflict(Dataset arg0, List<SyncConflict> arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onDatasetDeleted(Dataset arg0, String arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onDatasetsMerged(Dataset arg0, List<String> arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(DataStorageException arg0) {
            System.err.println("Error onSyncro: " + arg0.getMessage());
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Dataset arg0, List<Record> arg1) {
            System.out.println("Dataset Synchronized!");
        }
    });

}
}
```

**BYOIProvider Class**

```
package com.leversystems.authserver;

import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSAbstractCognitoIdentityProvider;

public class BYOIProvider extends AWSAbstractCognitoIdentityProvider {

    public static String id;
    public static String token;


    public BYOIProvider(String acctId, String identityPoolId) {
        super(acctId, identityPoolId);

    }

    @Override
    public String getProviderName() {

        return "com.leversystems.devauth";
    }

    @Override
    public String refresh() {
        update(id, token);
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Work Flow**

1. From android App when button is clicked, **getCredentials()** is called which gets token and id from Java Server Class.
2. Token and Id are then passed to **BYOIProvider Class** to update them.
3. **syncData()** is called which initializes CognitoCredentialProvider and BYOIProvider variables.
4. CognitoSyncManager is initialized with an object of CognitoCredentialProvider.
5. After this i receive an an exception error

> columns identity_id and dataset_name are not unique

on this line of code

> dataset = client.openOrCreateDataset("MyData");

**Update-1 (11-Nov-2014)**

ok I have now changed the return string of refresh() to token variable and this is the stacktrace.

```
11-11 12:58:52.196: I/View(29237): Touch down dispatch to android.widget.Button{4186d880 VFED..C. ........ 206,342-417,438 #7f080003 app:id/button1}, event = MotionEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, id[0]=0, x[0]=76.0, y[0]=34.0, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=228482273, downTime=228482273, deviceId=2, source=0x1002 }
11-11 12:58:52.213: D/GraphicBuffer(29237): create handle(0x5ed83e60) (w:720, h:1280, f:1)
11-11 12:58:52.222: I/SurfaceTextureClient(29237): [STC::queueBuffer] (this:0x5d12eb78) fps:0.10, dur:20282.80, max:20162.90, min:119.90
11-11 12:58:52.222: I/SurfaceTextureClient(29237): [STC::queueBuffer] this:0x5d12eb78, api:1, last queue time elapsed:20162.90
11-11 12:58:52.326: I/View(29237): Touch up dispatch to android.widget.Button{4186d880 VFED..C. ...P.... 206,342-417,438 #7f080003 app:id/button1}, event = MotionEvent { action=ACTION_UP, id[0]=0, x[0]=76.0, y[0]=34.0, toolType[0]=TOOL_TYPE_FINGER, buttonState=0, metaState=0, flags=0x0, edgeFlags=0x0, pointerCount=1, historySize=0, eventTime=228482404, downTime=228482273, deviceId=2, source=0x1002 }
11-11 12:58:52.327: V/Provider/Settings(29237):  from settings cache , name = sound_effects_enabled , value = 0
11-11 12:58:52.328: D/dalvikvm(29237): create interp thread : stack size=128KB
11-11 12:58:52.328: D/dalvikvm(29237): create new thread
11-11 12:58:52.328: D/dalvikvm(29237): new thread created
11-11 12:58:52.328: D/dalvikvm(29237): update thread list
11-11 12:58:52.329: D/dalvikvm(29237): threadid=15: interp stack at 0x60115000
11-11 12:58:52.329: D/dalvikvm(29237): threadid=15: created from interp
11-11 12:58:52.329: D/dalvikvm(29237): start new thread
11-11 12:58:52.329: D/dalvikvm(29237): threadid=15: notify debugger
11-11 12:58:52.329: D/dalvikvm(29237): threadid=15 (RefQueueWorker@org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ConnPoolByRoute@419852e8): calling run()
11-11 12:58:52.330: I/System.out(29237): httpget:http://192.168.1.112:8080/AuthenticationService/services/auth/gctbda
11-11 12:58:52.331: I/System.out(29237): http://192.168.1.112:8080/AuthenticationService/services/auth/gctbda
11-11 12:58:52.331: D/dalvikvm(29237): create interp thread : stack size=128KB
11-11 12:58:52.331: D/dalvikvm(29237): create new thread
11-11 12:58:52.332: D/dalvikvm(29237): new thread created
11-11 12:58:52.332: D/dalvikvm(29237): update thread list
11-11 12:58:52.332: D/dalvikvm(29237): threadid=16: interp stack at 0x60235000
11-11 12:58:52.332: D/dalvikvm(29237): threadid=16: created from interp
11-11 12:58:52.332: D/dalvikvm(29237): start new thread
11-11 12:58:52.333: D/dalvikvm(29237): threadid=16: notify debugger
11-11 12:58:52.333: D/dalvikvm(29237): threadid=16 (pool-3-thread-1): calling run()
11-11 12:58:52.336: I/System.out(29237): [socket][1] connection /192.168.1.112:8080;LocalPort=35830(10000)
11-11 12:58:52.336: I/System.out(29237): [CDS]connect[/192.168.1.112:8080] tm:10
11-11 12:58:52.336: D/Posix(29237): [Posix_connect Debug]Process com.leversystems.authserver :8080 
11-11 12:58:52.358: I/System.out(29237): [socket][/192.168.1.136:35830] connected
11-11 12:58:52.358: I/System.out(29237): [CDS]rx timeout:10000
11-11 12:58:52.358: I/System.out(29237): [CDS]SO_SND_TIMEOUT:0
11-11 12:58:52.360: I/System.out(29237): >doSendRequest
11-11 12:58:52.361: I/System.out(29237): <doSendRequest
11-11 12:58:53.259: I/AmazonWebServiceClient(29237): {cognito-sync, us-east-1} was not found in region metadata, trying to construct an endpoint using the standard pattern for this region: 'cognito-sync.us-east-1.amazonaws.com'.
11-11 12:58:53.259: D/CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(29237): Identity id is changed
11-11 12:58:53.259: D/CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(29237): Saving identity id to SharedPreferences
11-11 12:58:53.260: I/CognitoSyncManager(29237): identity change detected
11-11 12:58:53.271: W/System.err(29237): Exception in OnSuccess: columns identity_id, dataset_name are not unique (code 19)
```

**Update-2 (13-Nov-2014)**

Adding

> credentialsProvider.refresh();

after setLogins()/withLogins()

now if i try a wrong token it gives respective exception. When the token i am providing is correct it gives me this exception

```
Exception in onSuccess: Not authorized to perform sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity (Service: AWSSecurityTokenService; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: *SomeID*)
```

**Update-3 (13-Nov-2014)**

Ok so I have created a new role on IAM console. The Exception in the *Update-2* is now clear. The next problem is the same as the first one. Exact Exception I am receiving inside AsyncHttpClient is

```
11-13 15:40:41.738: I/AmazonWebServiceClient(23921): {cognito-sync, us-east-1} was not found in region metadata, trying to construct an endpoint using the standard pattern for this region: 'cognito-sync.us-east-1.amazonaws.com'.
11-13 15:40:41.739: D/CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(23921): Identity id is changed
11-13 15:40:41.739: D/CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(23921): Saving identity id to SharedPreferences
11-13 15:40:41.740: I/CognitoSyncManager(23921): identity change detected
11-13 15:40:41.749: W/System.err(23921): Exception in OnSuccess: columns identity_id, dataset_name are not unique (code 19)
```

**Update-4 (14/11/2014)**

My Updated Code and StackTrace

*Code:*

```
credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
            getApplicationContext(), cognitoProvider, null,
            AUTHORIZATION_ARN);

cognitoProvider.refresh();
```

*StackTrace:*

```
11-14 11:25:01.357: I/AmazonWebServiceClient(31084): {cognito-sync, us-east-1} was not found in region metadata, trying to construct an endpoint using the standard pattern for this region: 'cognito-sync.us-east-1.amazonaws.com'.
11-14 11:25:01.358: D/CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(31084): Identity id is changed
11-14 11:25:01.358: D/CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(31084): Saving identity id to SharedPreferences
11-14 11:25:01.358: I/CognitoSyncManager(31084): identity change detected
11-14 11:25:01.367: W/System.err(31084): Exception in OnSuccess: columns identity_id, dataset_name, key are not unique (code 19)
```

Comment: Would you please share the stacktrace? One minor problem in your code: BYOIProvider.refresh() should return the refreshed token instead of null.

Comment: kindly check the update in question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Yangfan mentioned, it's important that you make sure BYOIProvider.refresh() returns the token, not null. It is called internally by the CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider, and that token is used. Ideally, what is to happen is the communication with your server would take place in the BYOIProvider class, as the method calls from that class are used in the CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider.

That update call is important. It's what goes through and triggers the appropriate handling of identity changes (which could be what's causing your issue) and updating the token. It really needs to be called and have the appropriate token and identityId when doing so. If your getCredentials() call is used at all of the appropriate times, it could be enough to ensure that it returns the token, however if you were to move some of that code communicating with the server to inside the refresh call (above update) and update the return, it would handle itself.

If that doesn't resolve your issue, could you post your stacktrace?

Edit:

Alright, I see another possibility. AWSAbstractCognitoIdentityProvider actually keeps track of identityId and token - those are what are internally used in the credentials provider. It's possible this means the credentials provider isn't getting the identityId and token you're setting. These are accessible through getters and setters.

Additionally, in the docs for setLogins()/withLogins(), it says you should manually call refresh on the credentials provider after adding logins to the provider, as your identity id may have changed. The identity id of a user very much will change after they go from unauthenticated to authenticated.

Edit2: 
When an identity changes, a few things happen - one of which is the datasets, which are stored locally in a database, need to be removed from being linked to the old identity id and added to the new one. That action is triggered upon an identity changed listener being activated. Identity changed listeners are registered to the credentials provider upon initialization, but are activated upon an update call from the identity provider. That's why the order needs to be what it does, so the dataset is saved with the appropriate identity id and this error is avoided.

The error itself  could be caused by the following workflow: 
1) Save dataset a with authenticated identity id b 
2) Save dataset a with identity id c (by being unauthenticated, most likely) 
3) Authenticate back to identity id b. This will re-parent saved datasets from c to b, and cause the non-unique error to appear.

So, basically, you have to make sure when you save, you do so with the appropriate identity id so it is handled appropriately.

Comment: Thanks for that. Unfortunately, it appears to only have a few lines pertinent to Cognito specifically, and they're informational, not so much related to the error. Are you still having the same error? If so, do you have access to the part of the stack trace where it shows that error?

Comment: After you've updated those, could you try wiping app data? It's possible the issue you're facing  won't go away with these fixes unless you do so since it's saved to the local database.

Comment: Thanks, I have been wiping data since start and kindly check the UPDATE-2

Comment: Now I have made an Update-3, and also updated synchData() inside mainActivity. Check these please.

Comment: That error will only come up with multiple saves - are you sure you're clearing all of it? 

Example causing workflow:
1) Save dataset a with authenticated identity id b
2) Save dataset a with identity id c (by being unauthenticated, most likely)
3) Authenticate back to identity id b. This will re-parent saved datasets from c to b, and cause the non-unique error to appear.

Comment: It's possible, also, that the identity change listener isn't being triggered at the appropriate time. That gets triggered with the update call, but isn't registered until the credentials provider is set up, so what happens if you move cognitoProvider.refresh() to below the credentials provider initialization line?

Comment: What is with this exception raised by Cognito Sync? "Identity Change detected" is this problem because of this identity change? and why is change happening?

Comment: Updated my code again. check wipe function too. Sometimes it works fine and sometimes it gives me that error of identity_id and data_set not unique.

Comment: It's not an exception, no. It's informational. When an identity changes, a few things happen - one of which is the datasets, which are stored locally in a database, need to be removed from being linked to the old identity id and added to the new one. That action is triggered upon an identity changed listener being activated. Identity changed listeners are **registered** to the credentials provider upon initialization, but are **activated** upon an update call from the identity provider.

Comment: Just since I don't see it in your update, ensure you still call refresh on the credentials provider, just after you call it on the identity provider. Either way, you say it works sometimes and not others? Is there any notable difference in workflow?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64923/discussion-between-muneeb-mirza-and-jeff-bailey).